# DryIoc: injecting a proxy of a request-scoped service into singleton

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, dryioc

I have a number of services that ultimately depend on the request context but, as they are expensive to instantiate, I'd like to register them with `Reuse.Singleton`. That means I need to inject these singletons with some form of proxies of my scoped services.

I found that I can register a scoped service `A` normally and then inject it as `Func<A>`, allowing me to manually resolve `A` by invoking the injected delegate, i.e.

```
// DryIoC config
private static ConfigureDI(...)
{
    ...
    c.Register<A>(Reuse.InWebRequest);
    c.Register<B>(Reuse.Singleton);
    ...
}

// Scoped service
public class A 
{ 
    public object Foo() { ... }
}  

// Singleton service
public class B 
{ 
   private readonly Func<A> _a;

   public object Bar()
   {
       return _a().Foo();
   }
}
```

This approach seems to work, but I wonder: **is there a way to do this without having to modify the original classes?**

Comment: Such questions usually boil down to whether you can model them without DI library. If you can - then the sophisticated DI library can do this for you. So the question, how do you imagine it will work without DI lib, could you provide a sample?